# Booting into Windows from USB stick created on OSX

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot, usb

So I screwed up my Windows 7 laptop. I wanted to boot from memtest86 to try and diagnose an issue, but I apparently removed the option to boot to Windows. Unfortunately I don't have the Win7 install disc and it will take a couple days to mail it out here.

I tried getting ubcd on my Mac and I think I was able to burn it to a USB stick, but it won't boot ("No valid operating system"). I converted the .iso I downloaded to a .img file and used diskutil to burn it to the USB stick.

Comment: If you got the iso why didn't you burn it to a dvd instead?

Comment: I don't have any blank DVDs. I just moved, which is why I'm so short on stuff.

Comment: You would still need to set a mbr for the stick. Can you run unetbootin or win7flash on your mac? (maybe trough wine)?

Comment: I got unetbootin running in Wine and it copied the files onto the usb stick, but it still isn't bootable.

Comment: Try with win2flash

Comment: win2flash won't let me select my usb drive. It says `no devices found` and I can't manually put in `D:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an `.ISO` file, then just format your drive using 'NTFS' and copy or extract the files directly to your USB stick using PowerISO or WinRAR. It will become bootable.

But remember one thing: to boot from the USB you need to enable the "Boot from USB" option from your BIOS settings.

After booting from USB, do a startup repair.

Comment: I don't know if the filesystem format is the only thing that prevents the disk to boot, but I can confirm that I've copied an ISO into a hard drive via usb and it just worked fine. And it its, in fact, in NTFS format.

Comment: Yes because in the previous operating system(before 90's) we are using FAT(file allocation Table) which is only used for booting from the local file system but in the new operating system NTFS(New technology file System) which will allow to boot from the remote machine or any other external devices.

Comment: Great, I'll continue my research on it. +1 btw, because I didn't know about that too.